# Rails bundler issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, rubygems

i'm beginner rails developer, when i do bundle install it's return ok undle complete! 60 Gemfile dependencies, 148 gems now installed.
Use `bundle show [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.

If i Do rails s i've error

```
Could not find devise-4.1.1 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

if i do

```
lp git:(master) ✗ bundle show devise
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/devise-4.1.1
```

but i f do

```
gem -v devise
2.4.5.1
like git:(master) ✗
```

What can i do?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to launch the `rails s` within the bundle, like this: `bundle exec rails s`.

Comment: i'ts work fine, but i'm not sure that it is a good way.. 
Thanks!

Comment: There are different ways of doing this. I think this way is not the most concise and conveniant, but it's one that will always work: it doesn't rely on $PATH for finding rails, it strictly follows the specification of your current project by making all gems specified in the Gemfile available to require in your Ruby programs.
You might also `bundle install --binstubs` which will create in `./bin/rails` which might work.